# 'export * from' is undefined

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I have typescript file 'services.ts'

[image: services]

Suppose I want to import several modules.
If i write import like this

```
import { SchemaManager, SecurityManager } from '../../services.ts';
```

SchemaManager will be undefined in other module.

But if I write like this

```
import { SchemaManager } from '../../SchemaManager.ts'
```

SchemaManager will be initialized, and all will be ok.

I'am using webpack 4.32.2 and ts-loader 6.0.0 to build a project.
Earlier, I built this project with gulp@3.9.1 + webpack-stream@4.0.3 + ts-loader@3.5.0 and there was no such problem.

Comment: Is it possible that your `../views/gallery/ImageService` directly or indirectly import things from 'services.ts'?
Could be a circular reference issue.

Comment: No, ImageService does not import anything from services.ts. Can you explain why the problem might be in the ImageService?